# RESTORE DATABASE doesn't work, and doesn't report any error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I am executing a RESTORE DATABASE statement that often works, but occasionally does not work, and does not report any error. We are running against SQL Server 2008R2. A batch file is executing a sqlcmd statement to run sql statements from a file. The file contains the following (Note that the names are made up, but are correct because the restore usually works):

```
USE MASTER;
RESTORE DATABASE TestMLS
FROM DISK = 'c:\TestMLS.bak'
WITH MOVE 'CorrectName1' TO 'c:\TestMLS.MDF',
MOVE 'CorrectName2' TO 'c:\TestMLS.LDF',
REPLACE;
ALTER DATABASE E2SS80Test SET MULTI_USER;
```

While trying to find the issue, we enabled tracing with "DBCC TRACEON (3004, 3605, -1)" which gave the normal information that you would expect when the restore worked correctly. The output below is what the log shows when the restore does not work:

```
08/06/2013 13:42:25,spid59,Unknown,Setting database option MULTI_USER to ON for database TestMLS.
08/06/2013 13:42:25,spid59,Unknown,Resuming any halted fulltext crawls
08/06/2013 13:42:05,spid59,Unknown,X-locking database: TestMLS
08/06/2013 13:42:05,spid59,Unknown,Dismounting FullText catalogs
08/06/2013 13:42:05,spid59,Unknown,Halting FullText crawls on database TestMLS
08/06/2013 13:42:05,spid59,Unknown,Restore: Planning begins
08/06/2013 13:42:05,spid59,Unknown,Restore: Backup set is open
08/06/2013 13:42:05,spid59,Unknown,Restore: Configuration section loaded
08/06/2013 13:42:05,spid59,Unknown,Opening backup set
08/06/2013 13:42:05,spid59,Unknown,RestoreDatabase: Database TestMLS
```

Note that Restore: Planning begins happens, but Restore: Planning Complete never appears. In addition, Restore: BeginRestore never appears.

Today I found a workaround - previously the script did not take the database offline before calling the restore. Adding a statement to do that appears to allow the restore to work all of the time.

I would still like to know why we had this behavior at all - it seems that the restore process should at least fail with an error, instead of just not doing what was asked.

Any information or ideas are appreciated.

Comment: You're using batch files? Is it still 1998? You have modern programming tools like Powershell, .Net, SSIS, T-SQL, etc. which all have try/catch and can easily return errors like this.

Comment: Hi Brian - I appreciate the sentiment, but I didn't set up the architecture of how this works, and changing it would require changes to multiple programs that are part of the process, so that's not going to fly for us. As I mention in another comment, the batch file setup is reporting any error just fine - but there is simply no error that I can see in this case, neither returned from the execution of the command, nor in the sql server trace logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think restore sometimes doesn't happen because the database being replaced is in use at that time. Try adding this before `RESTORE DATABASE` command:

```
ALTER DATABASE [TestMLS] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
```

Comment: Thanks, yes, we are doing this now, and it appears to be working. However, there is no indication that the database was in use, and no reason we are aware of that it would be. Since there is no error reported, the cause of the issue is still unknown, and while it might be 'in use' somehow, it might as easily be something else. I'm trying to find out what it is for certain (in case some other problem needs to be addressed), and why the restore command just stops trying without giving an error.

Comment: Notice the "X-locking database: TestMLS" message (SQL Server tries to exclusively lock the database), then there's 20 seconds pause, then the process of obtaining exclusive lock times out, then it resumes full text crawl and executes your ALTER DATABASE SET MULTI_USER command. So the database is in use when you're trying to restore it. It's enough to have an empty SQL Server Management Studio query window open with this database set as current database.
I just did a test and it confirmed the above reasoning (I also had exactly the same sequence of messages in ERRORLOG).

Comment: Excellent, thanks again. I did not notice this because the x-locking entry appears in both the successful and unsuccessful logs. Since there's nothing that says it failed in the log, I thought it was successful in both cases. The problem certainly does occur on machines where SQL Management studio is not a part of the problem, but it looks like we can now start investigating why, intermittently, the database is still in use.

Comment: Very good. Hope you'll find the cause soon. Also check why it fails silently. RESTORE DATABASE is pretty verbose about the error (`Msg 3101, Level 16, State 1, Line 1. Exclusive access could not be obtained because the database is in use. Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1. RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.`), so if you maybe add some error handling to the batch file, you would be able to see the messages.

Comment: Wouldn't any error message be written to the server logs when the TRACEON was in place? I already ensured that the batch file is properly reporting errors that occurs in the execution of the SQL - there is no error anywhere that I can see in this case. We will continue looking.

Comment: In order to capture error messages sent by SQL Server to clients to the error log, you need to use 3602 and 3605 trace flags. Beware if you set them globally, not at session level, then the messages may clutter your log, depending on how many sessions are open and how many errors they generate.